# Cancelling Thread Timer from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I'm attempting to implement the MSDN example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx) for Thread.Timers in my own code.

I want to be able to cancel the timer when a certain user action is performed, however I can not dispose the timer, I suspect this is because I'm calling a method from another class so I need to adjust; but I don't know where.

Other than this, the timer works fine. Can anyone see why my timer will not cancel when btnconfigOpenConfig is called?

*FYI I'm converting what was a worker process to a timed event.*

```
public partial class Xservt : Window
        {

            internal class TimerStateObjClass
            {
                public int SomeValue;
                public System.Threading.Timer SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference;
                public bool TimerCanceled;
            }


internal void SomeMethod(){


                    TimerStateObjClass stateObj = new TimerStateObjClass();
                    stateObj.TimerCanceled = false;
                    stateObj.SomeValue = 100;
                    System.Threading.TimerCallback timerDelegate =
                        new System.Threading.TimerCallback(twit.hometimelineclass._sqlUpdateFromTwitterWorker_DoWork);

                    var sqlUpdateFromTwitterTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, stateObj, 0,20000);
                    stateObj.SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference = sqlUpdateFromTwitterTimer;

    }
}


//action to perform which disposes the timer
private void btnconfigOpenConfig(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                TimerStateObjClass timerState = new TimerStateObjClass();
                timerState.TimerCanceled = true;
    }


//Actions the timer is calling, in another class
internal static void _sqlUpdateFromTwitterWorker_DoWork(object StateObj)
            {

                Xservt.TimerStateObjClass state = (Xservt.TimerStateObjClass) StateObj;

                if(state.TimerCanceled)
                {
                    state.SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference.Dispose();

                }

    //some work
    }
```

Comment: You are creating *new* objects of TimerStateObjClass.  That can't work, add a private field to your class instead.

Comment: of type TimerStateObjClass, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans pointed out in the comments, you need to keep a reference to TimerStateObjClass you originally created.  You can then use that to set TimerCanceled.

```
public partial class Xservt : Window
{

    internal class TimerStateObjClass
    {
        public int SomeValue;
        public System.Threading.Timer SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference;
        public bool TimerCanceled;
    }

    TimerStateObjClass stateObj;  //THIS IS THE ORIGINAL STATE OBJ
    internal void SomeMethod()
    {
        stateObj = new TimerStateObjClass();
        stateObj.TimerCanceled = false;
        stateObj.SomeValue = 100;
        System.Threading.TimerCallback timerDelegate = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(twit.hometimelineclass._sqlUpdateFromTwitterWorker_DoWork);

        var sqlUpdateFromTwitterTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, stateObj, 0, 20000);
        stateObj.SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference = sqlUpdateFromTwitterTimer;
    }

    //action to perform which disposes the timer
    private void btnconfigOpenConfig(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //HERE WE CAN GET AT THE ORIGINAL STATE OBJ
        stateObj.TimerCanceled = true;
    }
}
    //Actions the timer is calling, in another class
    internal static void _sqlUpdateFromTwitterWorker_DoWork(object StateObj)
    {
        Xservt.TimerStateObjClass state = (Xservt.TimerStateObjClass)StateObj;

        if (state.TimerCanceled)
        {
            state.SqlUpdateFromTwitterTimerReference.Dispose();
        }

        //some work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to store reference to your timer (or class that references the timer) somewhere in your class.
2. To stop the timer there is not need to dispose it. You can just call `timer.Change(-1, -1);`. That will allow to re-enable timer again by calling `timer.Change(dueTimeInMs, intervalInMs);`

You code should be something like that:

```
public partial class Xservt : Window
{
   private Timer timer = new Timer(o => DoSomething());

   private void StartTimer()
   {
     var period = 5 * 1000; // 5 sec
     timer.Change(0, period);
   }

   private void StopTimer()
   {
     timer.Change(-1, -1);
   }
}
```

Then call `StartTimer` to run it and `StopTimer` to stop respectively.

Also note that if there is any chance that `DoSomething` will run longer than timer interval that would result in running that method in more than one thread concurrently. To avoid that DO NOT use Timer's interval but use `dueTime` instead:

```
   private Timer timer = new Timer(o => {
                                         DoSomething(); 
                                         StartTimer();
                                         });

   private void StartTimer()
   {
     var period = 5 * 1000; // 5 sec
     timer.Change(period, 0);
   }
```

In this timer is trigrered to run only once but after each run it gets re-triggered.